# Need to access the index of my excel using pandas python, I wanna print who and how much sold the most

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

so... I have this excel sheet, I have 4 employees with certain amounts of sells, I know how to print the biggest number, but I also wanna print who achieved it.

```
  Employee   Total Sells
0   Carlos     205301
1   Fernanda   204982
2   Theo       272816
3   Raquel     172700
```

Alright, what I've done so far:

```
sheet = pd.read_excel("/content/controle_da_empresa.xlsx", None)
employees_sheet = sheet["Employee"]
employees_sells = employees_sheet["Total Sells"]
print(max(employees_sells))
```

It is printing 272816, which is the biggest number, but I also wanna print the name of the person whom done it.

What I want to happen:
Let's say Theo sold the most: Theo, 272816
Something like this, pretty much the name and the number

Thank you guys, sorry for bothering, I'm a completely beginner to data science.

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
sheet.loc[sheet['Total Sells'].idxmax(), 'Employee']
```

**Output**

```
'Theo'
```

To print the entire row, just use -

```
sheet.loc[sheet['Total Sells'].idxmax(), :]
```

Comment: Hey buddy, thanks for the help, but it says that df is not defined...

Comment: @V2P `df` is just the dataframe os `sheet` in this case. Updated ans

Comment: Alright, thanks man, but now it says "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'loc'"

Comment: What is the data type of `sheet`? Is it a pandas dataframe? Also changed the accessor to `sheet`, check again

Comment: I did a type(sheet), it is a dict

Comment: it shouldn't be, it should be a `pandas.DataFrame` after loading it from `read_excel`

Comment: I converted into a df now, I guess: sheet_df = pd.DataFrame([sheet])

Comment: when I type(sheet), it returns: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Comment: I think the problem could be that Employee is not a numeric argument